# Issue using boolean compares in C

Tags: c

I am attempting to check for "y" or "n" and if the input is outside of that continue to ask the user to re-enter their response.

What I currently have:

```
do{
   printf("Press 'y' to go again or 'n' to quit: ");
   scanf("%s", goAgain);
   result = strncmp(goAgain, yes, 1);
   result2 = strncmp(goAgain, no, 1);
   printf("%d %d\n", result, result2);

}while(result != 0 || result2 != 0);
```

I know this isn't efficient, I've been trying random things while debugging.   In this setup  the yes and no are both char *  variables. yes contains "y" and no contains "n"

The output of the last printf gave me   0 for result and 11 for result2.   This should have dropped out of the do while since I used an OR.  Am I doing something obviously stupid or is there some quirk of C that I ma missing  (also...this is the first C program I have written so please explain a bit on any C specific suggestions)

Thanks

Edit: Thanks for the replies....that was a rather stupid mistake I should have caught.   Now, is there a better way of doing this? The way I have currently feels really clunky, and I don't see any way to make it all that much less clunky (other than directly moving the strncmp's into the while statement)

Comment: You need ``while(result==0 && result2==0);`.  You want to exit the loop if either variable is non 0.

Comment: It's "yes" "no", you need double quote string in C.

Comment: to answer your edited question, use %c, like [this](http://pastebin.com/K7Hut7HW)

Comment: "I don't see any way to make it all that much less clunky" That would be `while (*goAgain != 'y' && *goAgain != 'n')`, because you are limiting the comparison to a single character anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `result` is 0 and `result2` is 11, then

```
result != 0 || result2 != 0
0 != 0 || 11 != 0
false || true
true
```

which means the `while` loop will continue looping.

Comment: Facepalm....thank you..     Could you elaborate on a better way of doing this?   This setup feels really clunky compared to in Java (string.compareTo(string))

Comment: How would you write the loop in Java? Given that, you could pretty much translate it line by line to C.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm just overthinking things and letting myself be overwhelmed with the pointers and other quirks of C. Thanks a bunch for your help

Answer (score 1):

strncmp(str1,str2,num) function returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:

- A zero value indicates that the characters compared in both strings form the same string.
- A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

Comment: why put it as an answer if u cannot put it in comment because of low rep?

Answer (score 0):

```
char goAgain;
while(1){
    printf("hello\n");
    do{
        printf("\nPress 'y' to go again or 'n' to quit: ");
    }while(scanf(" %c", &goAgain) == 1 && goAgain != 'y' && goAgain != 'n');

    if(goAgain == 'n')//there is no need to check for 'y'
        break;
}
```